# Something about Riemann- Stieltjes integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, riemann-integration

I need some help with an specific problem about Riemann- Stieltjes integration

Let $\alpha$ be an increasing function on $[a,b]$. Let $f \in R(\alpha)$ in $[a,b]$ and suppose 
that for some positive number $M$, $|f(x)|>M$   for all $x\in [a,b]$. Prove that $1/f \in R(\alpha)$.

I would be really thankful if someone could bring me a little help

Comment: What do you mean by $R(\alpha)$ exactly?

Comment: @Dalamar Surely she means the functions that have a Riemann-Stieltjes integral with respect to $\alpha$.

Comment: I mean that $f$ belongs to set of integrable functions with respect to $\alpha$ in $[a,b]$

Comment: Hoping i'm not being shallow or flat out wrong, but the condition on $|f(x)|$ should allow you to bound your Riemann-Stieltjes sum for $1/f$  with something like $\sum_j \frac{1}{M}  (\alpha(x_j) - \alpha(x_{j-1}))$. Is this of any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Riemann Stieltjes integrability of $1/f$ it is necessary that $f\neq0$ in $[a,b]$. Since $\alpha$ is increasing then $f$ have to be bounded variation and by condition $|f(x)|>M $ for all $ x \in [a,b] $ we deduce that $1/f$ is also of bounded variation and so $1/f \in R(\alpha)$.

Comment: thank you. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: but, now that i'm giving a second look to your answer I think that given that $\alpha$ is increasing is  $\alpha$ who has to have bounded variation. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes every increasing (monotone) function is of bounded variation.

Comment: sorry But I'm not quite sure about something: If $\alpha$ and $f$ have bounded variation, can we assure that $f  \in R(\alpha)$ Don't we need also that $\alpha$ would be continuous?

Comment: One of $f$ and $\alpha$ have to be of bounded variation and other continuous. So $\alpha$ is bounded variation then $f$ must be continuous and so $1/f$ must be continuous since $f\neq 0$.

Comment: No, $f$ does not have to be of bounded variation. And bounded variation is not sufficient. Think about the case $\alpha(t)=t$: we all know that $f$ is Riemannn integrable if and only if it's bounded and continuous almost everywhere; bounded varation has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

For the Riemann integral it's easy to see that if $f$ is integrable, the range of $f$ is contained in an interval, and $\phi$ is continuous on that interval then $\phi\circ f$ is integrable.

It's not clear to me whether that holds for Riemann-Stieltjes integrals or not. But it's more or less obvious if $\phi$ satisfies a Lipschitz condition $|\phi(t)-\phi(s)|\le c|t-s|$.

So. The function $1/t$ is Lipschitz on $[M,\infty)$, because its derivative is bounded, hence $1/f$ is integrable wrt $\alpha$.

(The easiest way to see that a Lipschitz condition on $\phi$ is sufficient is probably in terms of upper and lower sums: If $|\phi(s)-\phi(t)|\le c|s-t|$ and $I=[x_{j-1},x_j]$ then $\sup_I\phi\circ f-\inf_I\phi\circ f\le c(\sup_I f-\inf_I f)$.)